# Delete elements from array in foreach in PHP (advanced)

Tags: php, arrays

Here is my problem:
I have an array with id's ($arr) which I'm slicing in groups of three. Next, I have an array with other id's ($otherIds) which I want to compare with main array ($arr), and if some of id's are identical - they should be deleted from rest of the $arr's chunks.

F.e. I have `$arr = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8)`, and `$otherIds = array(5, 7)`. I'm cutting $arr into the chunks of three elements, and then loop $arr in foreach and compare them to $otherIds, so in first iteration - code should see that $otherIds '5' and '7' exists in next chunks of $arr, and delete them.
My output should be:

- 1st iteration - array(1, 2, 3)
- 2nd iteration - array(4, 6) - 5 should be removed
- 3rd iteration - array(8) - 7 should be removed

`$otherIds` can be different in each iteration (they are taken from database), but to simplify it, I will use constant values.

Here is my code:

```
$arr = array(15, 10, 12, 17, 21, 13, 15, 25, 7, 18, 4, 1, 5, 2);

$chunks = array_chunk($arr, 3);
$ids = array();
foreach ($chunks as $k => $v) {
    $otherIds = array(6, 7, 22, 31, 44, 9, 17);
    $ids = $v;

    foreach ($chunks as $key => $val) {
        if ($key <= $k) continue;
        foreach ($chunks[$key] as $g => $ch) {
            foreach ($otherIds as $o) {
                if ($ch['id'] == $o) {
                    $ids[] = $o;
                    unset($chunks[$key][$g]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As You can see I use a lot of foreaches, but I cant see better solution...
Also, every next iteration of main foreach should be (as mentioned above) shortened by deleted elements from $otherIds - which I this code is NOT doing.

How to achieve it? Is there easier/better/more efficient solution?
I repeat: main goal is to check $otherIds in each iteration of main `foreach`, and delete same elements from $arr in other chunks.

Comment: Splitting in chunks is required?

Comment: Can't you just fetch the values first, remove them from the array and then split the array and loop over it?!

Comment: Investigate [`array_diff()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php). It does the two (three?) inner loops for you. It returns a new array that contains the values from the first array that are not present in the second array.

Comment: Why are you nesting " foreach" on the chunks within itself ?

Comment: @Rizier123 nope, cause the $otherIds is taken from id's

Comment: @user3526204 what do You mean?

Comment: @ u_mulder yes, they're required

Comment: I meant You have 'foreach ($chunks as $key => $val) ' within 'foreach ($chunks as $k => $v) ' ...i guess you have it that way, bcoz as you have mentioned in the  answer comment - $otherIds are dependent on the chunks....may be it gets populated from the chunks in some other part of your code...here it is not clear where the values in $otherIds are coming from ..so the confusion...

Comment: @user3526204 $otherIds are taken from database on each iteration, they are dependets on elements from $arr

Comment: Deleting elements during a foreach would be a very bad idea.  There are better tools for removing elements from an array, such as array_filter

Answer (score 0):

Try [`array_diff()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php):

```
$arr = array(15, 10, 12, 17, 21, 13, 15, 25, 7, 18, 4, 1, 5, 2);
$chunks = array_chunk($arr, 3);

// Build the filtered list into $output
$output = array();
foreach ($chunks as $k => $v) {
    $otherIds = array(6, 7, 22, 31, 44, 9, 17);
    // array_diff() returns the list of values from $v that are not in $otherIds
    $output[$k] = array_diff($v, $otherIds);
}

// Investigate the result
print_r($output);
```

#### Update

I re-read the question and I think I eventually understood the logic (which is not described in the sample data). On each iteration it gets a new set of IDs to ignore and removes them from all chunks, starting from the current chunk.

The updated code is:

```
$arr = array(15, 10, 12, 17, 21, 13, 15, 25, 7, 18, 4, 1, 5, 2);
$chunks = array_chunk($arr, 3);

// $chunks is numerically indexed; we can use for() to iterate it 
// (avoid assigning to $v a value that is never used)
$count = count($chunks);
for ($k = 0; $k < $count; $k ++) {
    $otherIds = array(6, 7, 22, 31, 44, 9, 17);

    // $chunks is numerically indexed; start with key `$k` to iterate it
    for ($key = $k; $key < $count; $key ++) {
        // remove the values from $otherId present in the chunk
        $chunks[$key] = array_diff($chunks[$key], $otherIds);
    }
}
```

Comment: Cant you put the $otherIds array outside the foreach loop... rather than reassign it every time ?

Comment: This is how the code in the question initializes it. And it's like that because it is a question requirement: *"`$otherIds` can be different in each iteration (they are taken from database), but to simplify it, I will use constant values."

Comment: @user3526204 nope, they are dependent on the id's from chunks

Comment: @axiac ok, but I want to delete them from $arr - so in next foreach iteration, there wont be elements from $otherIds...

Comment: I guess it will help if you show how $otherIds is getting populated

Comment: @user3526204 - see my answer to you above

Comment: @user7391441 use reference in `foreach ($chunks as & $v)` and reasign `$v = array_diff($v, $otherIds)`

Comment: @user7391441 I'm not sure I understand what you want. Your code doesn't change `$arr`. Anyway, if you want to update `$chunks` on each iteration just drop `$output` and put the result of `array_diff()` into `$chunks[$k]` instead. Maybe the example you posted doesn't cover all the cases. Please modify the input and output data in the question to show a case that is not covered by my code.

Answer (score 0):

When you modify an array you are iterating in a foreach loop, you mess up internal pointer in the array and things get confused.

Make a copy while picking up the triplets, do not do `unset()` nor modify the original array. Thanks to the copy-on-write feature in PHP, the copy will be fast and cost effective, even if the elements are big structures, not only numbers.

Comment: Can you please post any more details? I have no idea what You are talking about....

Comment: PHP's Array has an internal pointer. This pointer is used by foreach loop as well as `key()`, `value()`, `next()`, and other functions. When you remove an element from the array, its internal pointer moves in undefined manner and it causes troubles, like foreach skipping another element or so.